# Можно ли использовать ScrollView с несколькими виджетами разного типа?

Tags: python, kivy

Я пишу приложение на Python Kivy и мне нужно сделать прокрутку виджетов Label и TextInput. Я для этого использую ScrollView, но с 2-мя виджетами разного типа ScrollView не работает, то есть к примеру:

ScrollView:
Label:
text: "работает"

ScrollView:
Label:
text: "не работает"
Button:
text: "не работает

Можно ли как-то реализовать прокрутку разных виджетов?

Простите если, что то непонятно или глупо объяснил, я начинающий программист.

Зарание спасибо !!!